# combine jquery code . show only current one hide other

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, accordion

I am new in jquery. I am trying to make a toggle accordion type things. i will have some a tag and will have some div . if i click the first a tag portion of the first div will show. other divs portion will be hidden. here how I am doing it but how can I combine to make the code small and clean. thanks

```js
jQuery(function() {

  jQuery('.tab_link1').click(function() {

    jQuery("#first_tab .tab_main_cont1").slideToggle();
    jQuery("#first_tab .tab_icon").toggleClass("icon_rotate");

    jQuery("#second_tab .tab_main_cont1").hide();
    jQuery("#third_tab .tab_main_cont1").hide();
    jQuery("#fourth_tab .tab_main_cont1").hide();
    jQuery("#fifth_tab .tab_main_cont1").hide();
    jQuery("#sixth_tab .tab_main_cont1").hide();
    jQuery("#seventh_tab .tab_main_cont1").hide();
    jQuery("#eighth_tab .tab_main_cont1").hide();
    jQuery("#nineth_tab .tab_main_cont1").hide();


  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>
    <a class="tab_link1" href="#first_tab"><img src="image url here" alt="360 icon"></a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a class="tab_link2" href="#second_tab"><img src="image url here" alt="360 icon"></a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a class="tab_link3" href="#third_tab"><img src="image url here" alt="360 icon"></a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a class="tab_link4" href="#fourth_tab"><img src="image url here" alt="360 icon"></a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a class="tab_link5" href="#fifth_tab"><img src="image url here" alt="360 icon"></a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a class="tab_link6" href="#sixth_tab"><img src="image url here" alt="360 icon"></a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a class="tab_link7" href="#seventh_tab"><img src="image url here" alt="360 icon"></a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a class="tab_link8" href="#eighth_tab"><img src="image url here" alt="360 icon"></a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a class="tab_link9" href="#nineth_tab"><img src="image url here" alt="360 icon"></a>
  </li>

</ul>


<div id="first_tab">
  <div class="tab_main_cont1">
    some text
  </div>
</div>


<div id="second_tab">
  <div class="tab_main_cont1">
    some text
  </div>
</div>
<div id="third_tab">
  <div class="tab_main_cont1">
    some text
  </div>
</div>
<div id="fourth_tab">
  <div class="tab_main_cont1">
    some text
  </div>
</div>
<div id="fifth_tab">
  <div class="tab_main_cont1">
    some text
  </div>
</div>
<div id="sixth_tab">
  <div class="tab_main_cont1">
    some text
  </div>
</div>
<div id="seventh_tab">
  <div class="tab_main_cont1">
    some text
  </div>
</div>
<div id="eighth_tab">
  <div class="tab_main_cont1">
    some text
  </div>
</div>
<div id="nineth_tab">
  <div class="tab_main_cont1">
    some text
  </div>
</div>
```

As you can see I have to do it for every link. How can I combine? thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this . you are adding `target` element in your href .So apply show event in targeted element.And hide all other elements use this `jQuery(".tab_main_cont1").hide();`

```js
jQuery(function() {
  jQuery('a[class^="tab_link"]').click(function() {
    jQuery(".tab_main_cont1").hide();
    jQuery($(this).attr('href')).children('.tab_main_cont1').slideDown();
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>
    <a class="tab_link1" href="#first_tab"><img src="image url here" alt="360 icon"></a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a class="tab_link2" href="#second_tab"><img src="image url here" alt="360 icon"></a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a class="tab_link3" href="#third_tab"><img src="image url here" alt="360 icon"></a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a class="tab_link4" href="#fourth_tab"><img src="image url here" alt="360 icon"></a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a class="tab_link5" href="#fifth_tab"><img src="image url here" alt="360 icon"></a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a class="tab_link6" href="#sixth_tab"><img src="image url here" alt="360 icon"></a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a class="tab_link7" href="#seventh_tab"><img src="image url here" alt="360 icon"></a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a class="tab_link8" href="#eighth_tab"><img src="image url here" alt="360 icon"></a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a class="tab_link9" href="#nineth_tab"><img src="image url here" alt="360 icon"></a>
  </li>

</ul>


<div id="first_tab">
  <div class="tab_main_cont1">
    some text1
  </div>
</div>


<div id="second_tab">
  <div class="tab_main_cont1">
    some text2
  </div>
</div>
<div id="third_tab">
  <div class="tab_main_cont1">
    some text3
  </div>
</div>
<div id="fourth_tab">
  <div class="tab_main_cont1">
    some text4
  </div>
</div>
<div id="fifth_tab">
  <div class="tab_main_cont1">
    some text5
  </div>
</div>
<div id="sixth_tab">
  <div class="tab_main_cont1">
    some text6
  </div>
</div>
<div id="seventh_tab">
  <div class="tab_main_cont1">
    some text7
  </div>
</div>
<div id="eighth_tab">
  <div class="tab_main_cont1">
    some text8
  </div>
</div>
<div id="nineth_tab">
  <div class="tab_main_cont1">
    some text9
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I need to show the parent div like "first_tab", "second_tab" etc. only need to hide the "tab_main_cont1" section of the div

Comment: see my updated answer  .Please use latest version library of jquery or use with `slideDown()`